# Dynamically add li and div to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list I am dynamically adding to an html page using an ajax call. I am adding the list items like this:

code in Jquery:

```
$.getJSON('getData.php', function(result){
    $.each(result,  function(index, results) {

        $('#myList').append('<li>'+results.title+'</li>');
    });

});
```

What I want to do is dynamcially add a div to add the li list to. So every time the list items are added they are added to a div.

A desired output would be someting like this:

```
<div>
  <li>First Added item</li>
  <li>Second Added item</li>
  <li>Third added itme</li>
</div>
```

This was my attempt at the solution:

```
  $.getJSON('getChapterFilter.php', {name: bookSel}, function(result){

    var appendDiv = false;
    var appendEnd = false;
    $.each(result,  function(index, results) {

        if (appendDiv === false) {
            $('#myList').append('<div>');
            appendDiv = true;
            }
        else {

        $('#myList').append('<li>'+results.title+'</li>');
        }

        if(appendEnd === false) {
            $('#myList').append('</div>');
            appendEnd = true;
            }
     });

  });
```

The Trouble I am having is the li do not populate in the list. This is what is happening with the above code:

```
<div></div>
<li>first added item</li>
<li>second added item</li>
<li>third added item</li>
```

Comment: Target the div and append to that.  Try $('#myList').find('div').append(...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you append to a div in your loop, then append the div to your list?

Example

```
$.getJSON('getData.php', function(result){
    var $myDiv = $('<div>'); // create div

    $.each(result,  function(index, results) {
        $myDiv.append('<li>' + results.title + '</li>'); // append list item to div
    });

    $('#myList').append($myDiv); // append div to myList
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#myList').append('<div>');
```

This will append a `<div></div>` to `#myList`

To add your `<li>` inside the div you have to do the following:

```
$('#myList > div').append('<li>'+results.title+'</li>');
```

To shorten it up a bit you can do this:

```
$.getJSON('getChapterFilter.php', {name: bookSel}, function(result){
    $("#myList").append("<div>" + result.reduce( function(p,c){ return p + "<li>" + c.title + "</li>" }, "" ) + "</div>" );
});
```

Comment: this won't loop through the result set to populate the list.

Answer (score 1):

Just append a `<div>` element to #myList and assign it to a variable.

```
$.getJSON( 'getData.php', function( result ) {

    var $container = $( '<div>' ).appendTo( '#myList' );

    $.each( result, function( index, results ) {

        $container.append( '<li>' + results.title + '</li>' );

    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to an answer:

Target the div and append to that. Right now you are targeting the item with id='myList' and appending everything onto the end of it.

Try:

```
    $('#myList').find('div').append(...)
```

Adding extra explination...
What the .find() does is search inside of $('#myList') for any/all 'div' element(s).  You need to be a little careful here because if there is more than one div there they will ALL get the append.  If this is a concern then you can adjust with

```
    $('#myList').first('div').append(...);
```

or

```
    $('#myList').find('div').eq(0).append(...);
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you append `<div>` at the very beginning, your web browser will be like "Whoa, that's not valid HTML because the tag never closes; I'll just add a closing tag real quick" and instantly closes your div tag, causing the output you're seeing. To achieve your goal with this approach, you'd want something like this:

```
var appendDiv = false;
var appendEnd = false;
var myHtml = "";
$.each(result,  function(index, results) {
    if (appendDiv === false) {
        myHtml += '<div>';
        appendDiv = true;
        }
    else {

    myHtml += '<li>'+results.title+'</li>';
    }

    if(appendEnd === false) {
        myHtml += '</div>';
        $('#myList').append(myHtml);
        appendEnd = true;
        }
 });
```

});

This way, the browser doesn't try to evaluate the HTML you are creating until you are done writing it, so it processes correctly. (granted, hand-crafted HTML via strings still might not be the best approach)

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, `<li>` element should be in `<ul>` or `<ol>` element, NOT IN `<div>`.**

To do what you want, you should do this:

1. Append `<ul>` into your document
2. Select the added `<ul>`
3. Then append `<li>...</li>` into the selected `<ul>`

**The first example:**

```
var $myList = $('#myList');

$myList.append('<ul/>');
$myList.find('ul').append('<li>...</li>');
```

**The second example:**

```
var $ul = $('<ul/>');

$ul.appendTo($('#myList'));
$ul.append('<li>...</li>');
```

**In a loop better way is:**

```
$.getJSON('getChapterFilter.php', {name: bookSel}, function(result){
    var $myListWrap = $('#myListWrap'),
        $myList     = $('<ul/>'),
        listData    = '';

    $myList.appendTo($myListWrap);

    $.each(result, function(index, results) {
        listData += '<li>' +results.title+ '</li>';
    });

    $myList.append(listData);
});
```